# Excel Processes Still Running After Program Termination

Tags: c#, excel, com, process, interop

I have written some C# programs that read from Excel files and output Excel files.  However, I have noticed that at the end of the day I have a LOT of Excel processes still running after the programs have terminated and all files have been closed.  Here is how I am handling the file creation and closing:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
...
wb.Close(true, saveDirectory + "\\" + reportName, false);
xlApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
this.Close();
```

Am I missing something?  Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: I'd say that looks pretty straight forward. Perhaps you could write a short Console program that loops through 1000 or so itterations while watching the processes on your PC. My guess is something not shown in the `...` section could be causing your problem.

Comment: I think you should find your answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not releasing all COM references (e.g. `xlApp.Workbooks.Add` creates a reference to a `Workbooks` object that is never released).  Therefore the Excel instance does not close, as described in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317109), and discussed at length in numerous StackOverflow questions.

The Excel instances will eventually shut down after your process has terminated, when COM detects that there hasn't been a ping from the client for a while.

Comment: I have changed `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
` to `while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb) != 0) {     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);}`  Will that do the trick?

Comment: @Kevin - no, that won't be enough.  It doesn't release the Workbooks object you reference using `xlApp.Workbooks.Add`.  Also you should use `try/finally` to ensure you release objects even if an exception is thrown.